# Prevent Divs From Scrolling Right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have several hidden divs (class="page")that are shown and animated when their links are clicked.  These divs contain horizontally scrollable divs (class="content") using the mCustomScrollbar plugin.  The first time the hidden div is revealed the scrollbars are in the home position (scrolled fully left). The next time the hidden div is revealed the scrollbars appear scrolled fully right, instead of in the home position.  I have tried using

```
$('.content').scrollLeft(0);
```

when the links are clicked, in order to scroll all instances of this class back to home.  This hasn't worked, and the API Documentation noted that .scrollLeft() does not work for hidden divs, so I called .scrollLeft() only on the id's of the .content divs that were being revealed, making sure to place the method call after the .page div had been changed to display:block

Can anyone shed any light on how to make sure the .content divs are scrolled fully left upon reveal?  Here is the link to the page: http://cdhbrooksdesign.com/home.html

Click on the "Productions" tab once to reveal, and it looks correct.  Click again to retract, then click a third time and the scroll sections are scrolled all the way to the right.

Many thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: you should create a fiddle for this so it is easier to debug: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Your code doesn't work, here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cMmq9/)

Comment: without the plugins that I have downloaded and linked, a jsfiddle will not work.  I will work on getting a jsfiddle running, but in the mean time, any suggestions would be welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime the hidden div needed to extend, adding the lines:

```
$('.content').mCustomScrollbar("disable",true);
$('.content').mCustomScrollbar("update");
```

Did the trick.  Below is the click function.  Hopefully someone else can find this useful as well.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#current").click(function(){
            if (currentIndex == 1){
                retractPage();
            }
            else if (sumIndex() !=0){
                retractExtend("currentPage", "current");
                currentIndex=1;
                $('.content').mCustomScrollbar("disable",true);
                $('.content').mCustomScrollbar("update");
            }
            else {
                extendPage("currentPage", "current");
                currentIndex=1;
                $('.content').mCustomScrollbar("disable",true);
                $('.content').mCustomScrollbar("update");
            }

        });
```